# How to write Automation script to check the UI changes?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to write automation script for testing the UI change, for example i have toggle button to view the same data in card view and list view , how to validate the toogle button works fine?

Comment: Please provide some details on what you already tried to do. Post some code etc.

Comment: Provide some HTML and the code attempts.

Comment: Since i am new to automation , just wanted to check is possible to test the view changes in automation.

Answer (score -1):

Are you already using any automation tool or selenium webdriver? If you are using webdriver, you can check for the change in UI content/elements to verify your toggle button worked fine.